# How to pass and replace a parameter to a TileServer GL styling JSON-file

Tags: parameters, tile-server, configuration, maptiler

I know it is a very specific question, but I am wondering if it's possible to pass a (key-)parameter like `...?key=1234` to a styling file which will be consumed by the **TileServer GL**? My styling file looks similar to the following snippet:

```
{ 
  "version": 8, 
  "name": "basic", 
  "metadata": { 
    "mapbox:type": "template" 
  }, 
  "sources": { 
    "openmaptiles": { 
      "type": "vector", 
      "url": "http://localhost:8100/data/v3.json?key={key}" 
    } 
  }, 
"glyphs": "http://localhost:8100/fonts/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf?key={key}", 
"layers": [ 

...
```

I want Tileserver GL to actually replace the {key} parameter with 1234 as mentioned above and use the new URL for further requests (further requests shall lead to: http://localhost:8100/data/v3.json?key=1234).

Currently, when I just pass a parameter in the original request (e.g.: http://localhost:8100/styles/basic/style.json?key=1234), Tileserver GL just ignores the parameter even though the server needs the JSON file and its included URL's for the upcoming requests.

- [Code](https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-gl)
- [Doc](https://tileserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here we use to reference the openmaptiles url the following syntax

`"url": "mbtiles://{maptiles}"`

Ps.: we have an entry for the maptiles keyword in the config.json

```
"data": {
    "maptiles": {
      "mbtiles": "yourTileFile.mbtiles"
    }
}
```

And for the glyphs we used that

"{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",